# How to make a project password protected in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I want to make my project, password protected in Net beans 7.1. If anyone try to make any changes in the files or while importing new project, user needs to enter the password.Is this feature enabled by default when installing Net beans itself or we need to do any steps?

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats not possible with Netbeans. If you use svn/git/cvs etc. you can create write-accounts only for persons who are allowed to make changes.

If you realy need a password protection for your projects you have to use an external program. You may consider [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) here.

In case of you want prevent users from working with your (compiled) code you can use an obfuscator like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). Some more obfuscators are listed here: http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Development_Tools/Obfuscators/